# Shortest path algorithm with both vertex and edge costs

Tags: algorithm, graph

This is a general algorithm question. I want to run some shortest path algorithm on an undirected graph where both edges and vertices have costs associated with them. Most of the shortest path finding algorithms do not take the vertex costs into account. Is there any method to compensate this problem?

Comment: For each edge, add half of the cost of the corresponding vertices to the edge cost and ignore vertex costs then.

Comment: Wouldn't it exaggerate the cost of vertices? If a vertex has 4 edges that connect to it, the cost of that vertex would be added 2 times.

Comment: Take a look on Prim's algorithm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Augment the graph by adding half the cost of the two vertices an edge connects to the cost of the edge (call that the augmented cost of the edge).

Then ignore the vertex costs and run an ordinary shortest path algorithm on the augmented graph.

For each path

```
v_0 -e_1-> v_1 -e_2-> v_2 -e_2-> ... -e_n-> v_n
```

the cost in the augmented graph is

```
(1/2*C(v_0) + C(e_1) + 1/2*C(v_1)) + (1/2*C(v_1) + C(e_2) + 1/2*C(v_2)) + ... + (1/2*C(v_(n-1)) + C(e_n) + 1/2*C(v_n))
= C(v_0) + C(e_1) + C(v_1) + C(e_2) + ... + C(e_n) + C(v_n) - 1/2*(C(v_0 + C(v_n))
```

so the cost of a path between two vertices `a` and `b` in the augmented graph is the cost of the same path in the original graph minus half the combined cost of the start and end vertices.

Thus a path is a shortest path in the original graph if and only it is a shortest path in the augmented graph.

Comment: In the Algorithm Design Manual by S. Skiena it is mentioned that if we are given a graph whose weights are on the vertices instead of the edges, we can consider the cost of the directed edge (i,j) to be cost of vertex j. Then, the problem is solved by running Dijkstra's algorithm Could we follow the same approach in this problem? It's not very clear to me why we should add half the cost of each vertex instead.

Comment: @antonis_wrx Here we have an undirected graph, so you don't know in which direction an edge may be traversed in the solution, hence you don't know the cost of which vertex to add to the edge cost. If it were a directed graph, one could also add the cost of the end vertex of each edge to the edge's cost.

Comment: Why do you only add **half** of the sum of the vertex costs to the edge?

Comment: @1110101001 Because every vertex on the path, except the start and end vertex, is taken into account twice, once for the edge ending in that vertex, and once for the edge starting in that vertex, so the sum of the augmented costs of the edges counts the original cost of the used vertices exactly once (or, if the path has a loop, as often as the vertex is visited), with the exception of start and end vertex, which are counted only half. But since that difference is path-independent, the relative costs of paths are kept in order.

Comment: Could we consider it general way of dealing with hyperGraph Structure ? That is a graph where each edge is an hyper-edges ?