# Superset of Ranges -- Finding greatest distance

Tags: algorithm, range, dynamic-programming

I have a list of ranges, each with an associated cost. An example is this:

```
1 to 1 | distance 10
1 to 2 | distance 9
2 to 3 | distance 8
3 to 4 | distance 2
```

I want to build the range with maximum distance (call it L) from the given ranges, under the condition that every range chosen to be added "L" must be a superset of "L". "L" starts off as an empty range so anything is a superset of it.

For example, in the given ranges,

```
Take the first range [1..1] and then the range [1..2]
which combined gives a distance of 19.
```

Explanation:

```
Since L is originally empty, [1..1] has the greatest distance so it is now L.
L is now [1..1] whose only superset is [1..2] so that is now L.
L is now [1..2] which has no supersets so the greatest possible distance is 10 + 9 = 19.
```

---

I'm pretty sure this is a dynamic programming problem, but I don't know the recurrence relation that can be used. Is this the most efficient way to go about doing this? Can anyone help?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, building a range with max distance is trivial in your example; you just include the whole range. Are there additional constraints I'm missing (like, for instance, the possibility of negative distances)? Otherwise, I think DP is overkill.

Comment: As mentioned in my post, the condition is that "every range chosen to be added "L" must be a superset of 'L'." Including the whole range won't work.

Comment: Why do you assume that the elementary range with the greatest distance must be part of the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each pair of ranges, build an adjacency matrix (i->j) which means i is a subset of j. You will end up with multiple directed graphs (some of them disconnected from each other).

The adjacency matrix can be built as follows:

First sort all the start times and end times in ascending order.
Then traverse this from left to right and keep a **deque (double ended queue)** of active interval start times in sorted order.
Whenever a start point is reached, push_back the interval in the deque.
Whenever an end point is reached, it becomes the sub-interval of all intervals in the list whose start times are less than that interval. Pop this interval out from the **front. This shall ensure a time complexity of O(number of super-sets of the interval)**
Complexity of this operation shall be O(n+E) where n is the number of intervals and E is the number of edges.

For each graph, the problem now is finding the longest path in an acyclic directed graph. This [link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-longest-path-directed-acyclic-graph/) explains how to solve this problem, with a minor variation that in your problem the costs are associated with nodes rather than edges.

EDIT: for the example intervals:

```
1a to 1b | distance 10
1c to 2a | distance 9
2b to 3a | distance 8
3b to 4 | distance 2
```

The sorted list of start and end times:

```
1a, 1c, 1b, 2b, 2a, 3b, 3a, 4
```

Whenever the start and end times coincide, we take the start time before the end time.

```
The deque is empty initially.   
1a added to deque from the back (start time of 1st interval).  
1c added to deque (start time of 2nd interval)  
The deque is now ___1a1c____ (double ended)  
1b (end time of 1st interval encountered)
```

Now pop from the front till you get its start time (1a).

```
____1c_____
```

Now we see that 1c is equal to 1a, hence we know that the interval whose end time is reached is a subinterval of the interval of 1c. So we build an edge from interval 1 to interval 2.

Next 2b is added to deque (start time of 3rd interval)

```
_____1c2b___
```

2a is then encountered (end time of 2nd interval)

```
_____2b____
```

Now we see that unlike the 1st pop, here 1c is not equal to 2b, hence there is no subinterval relationship.

Next 3b is added to deque (start time of 4th interval)

```
_____2b3b___
```

3a is then encountered (end time of 3rd interval)

```
_____3b____
```

Here again we see that, 2b is not equal to 3b, hence there is no subinterval relationship.

Similarly for the last interval.

So we see that we only end up with 1 edge in the graph and rest all are just one node graphs without any edges.

```
Graph 1 cost: 10 + 9 = 19.
Graph 2 cost: 8.
Graph 3 cost: 2
```

.

Comment: Doesn't building the matrix take O(n^2) time?

Comment: I don't quite understand how you build the adjacency matrix. Could you give an example using the ranges given in the original post?

Comment: @user2612743 Example added. The key here is that operations are done on both sides of the deque (front and back) as required.

Comment: Thanks so much! One last thing - for finding the longest path in DAG with the costs at the vertices, can you just change it so the costs are at the edges by making the edge cost between A and B be the cost[A] + cost[B]?

Comment: What do you do if the test data were like this? (I put it on pastebin as the comments here do not preserve formatting)

http://pastebin.com/TP7mvuef

Comment: Also, what about || 1S 11E | 3S 8E | 4S 10E || -- If I followed your algorithm correctly, it finds 4S,10E as a subset of 1S,11E, but it does not find 3S,8E as a subset of 1S,11E.

Comment: @user2612743 I don't think I explained clearly. After popping out the last item you have to push in to the front all the remaining items that you popped. You should keep a stack of the popped out items and then re-insert them in the queue once you find your matching start time.

Comment: @user2612743 regarding your question, you should add half the cost of both vertices to get the cost of the edge. See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105968/shortest-path-algorithm-with-both-vertex-and-edge-costs

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you, but what would you do if you had (6,7a) and (7b, 7c)? You would sort it as 6, 7b, 7a, 7c -- the deque would look like "6, 7b" when you encounter 7a you need to find any start time <= 6 but nothing satisfies it. But clearly 6,7 is a subset of 7,7

Comment: @user2612743 Such boundary conditions shall have to be taken care of while implementing the algorithm, it shall not be difficult to do so.